# Prob. 15, Chap. 3 in Baby Rudin: Can we not generalize the power series theorem to vector coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Here's Theorem 3.39 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Given the power series $\sum c_n z^n$, put $$ \alpha = \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left\vert c_n \right\vert}, \ \ \ R = \frac{1}{\alpha}.$$ (If $\alpha = 0$, $R = +\infty$; if $\alpha = +\infty$, $R=0$.) Then $\sum c_n z^n$ converges if $\vert z \vert < R$, and diverges if $\vert z \vert > R$.

And, here is Definition 3.38:

> Given a sequence $\left\{ c_n \right\}$ of complex numbers, the series $$\sum c_n z^n$$ is called a **power series**. The numbers $c_n$ are called the **coefficients** of the series; $z$ is a complex number.

Now my question is, does the follows hold?

> Let $k$ be a fixed natural number. Let $\left\{ \mathbf{a_n} \right\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{C}^k$. Let $z$ be a complex number. Let $$\alpha = \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left\vert \mathbf{a_n} \right\vert}, \ \ \ R = \frac{1}{\alpha}.$$ (If $\alpha = 0$, $R = +\infty$; if $\alpha = +\infty$, $R = 0$.) Then the series $\sum \mathbf{a_n} z^n$ converges if $\vert z \vert < R$, and diverges if $\vert z \vert > R$.

Now here's Prob. 15, Chap. 3 in Rudin:

> Definition 3.21 can be extended to the case in which the $a_n$ lie in some fixed $\mathbb{R}^k$. Absolute convergence is defined as convergence of $\sum \left\vert \mathbf{a_n} \right\vert$. Show that Theorems 3.22, 3.23, 3.25(a), 3.33, 3.34, 3.42, 3.45, 3.47, and 3.55 are true in this more general setting. (Only slight modifications are required in any of the proofs.)

Finally, here's Theorem 3.33 in Rudin:

> Given $\sum a_n$, put $\alpha = \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left\vert a_n \right\vert}$. Then
>
> (a) if $\alpha < 1$, $\sum a_n$ converges;
>
> (b) if $\alpha > 1$, $\sum a_n$ diverges;
>
> (c) if $\alpha = 1$, the test gives no information.

Can we not apply the generalized form of Theorem 3.33 for $\mathbb{C}^k$ to obtain (a proof of) the generalized form of Theorem 3.39?

Comment: can you give a sum and a commutative multiplication for them?

Comment: @janmarqz what do you mean by "for them"? And, what do you mean by "commutative multiplication"? You see, we can (commutatively) multiply two complex numbers. Right? And, we can multiply a vector with complex numbers as components by a complex scalar. Right? So can we generalize Theorem 3.33 to $\mathbb{C}^k$, Right? And, Theorem 3.39 is based on Theorem 3.33.

Comment: Im not sure that this can be generalized for sequences but for vectors is clear. You surely know the theorem that says that a limit in $\Bbb K^n$ converges if and only if the limit of each projection converges.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud, the $\mathbf{a}_n$ of yours